# swiftUI: Updating button and toggle text when user tapping (button inside button)

Tags: swiftui

I have a good feature by translating text on fly by toggling text by tapping.
But a lot of server working is too expansive.
I would like to update it little, but not imagine, how can I do this by toggling text in view.

Logic now:
when text is loaded - It automaticaly sending to server request user's language phone & if it != language on view - it can be translated. This feature load a lot of traffic api.

Logic I whant:
Text simply loaded -> Button with text (Do you want to translate text?) & only after that - by tapping on it - it will send requests to server.
Have tried by .onTapGesture and Toggle widget, but cannot realize that. By this logic - same text on original language will duplicate below text. (But in this case request really sending only when user tap again).
But view not good...
I want to make this logic:
Original text with button below (Do you want to translate?)->Tap on it->appearing another button (Translate)->Tapping on it - sending request and toggeling text.
Here is code now:
UPD. Full View

```
struct stepDetailItemView: View {
    var item: stepDetailItem
    @ObservedObject var translate = GoogleTranslate()
    var recipeName:String?
    @State var image: Image? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    VStack {
                    if image != nil {
                        GeometryReader { reader in
                            image!
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .offset(y: -reader.frame(in: .global).minY)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: reader.frame(in: .global).minY + 350)
                        }.frame(height: 350, alignment: .center)
                        
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        DetailCardShimmer().padding(.top)
                            }
                    }
                    Group {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                if recipeName != nil {
                                    Text("\(recipeName!)").font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("SubLabelTextColor"))
                                        .padding(.top)
                                }
                                else {
                                    Text("No recipe name").font(.headline).padding(.horizontal)
                                }
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(LocalizedStringKey("Step")).font(.headline)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("LabelTextColor"))
                                            .bold()
                                        Text("\(item.number+1)").font(.headline)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("LabelTextColor"))
                                            .bold()
                                    }
                                    Text(LocalizedStringKey("Step description")).font(.headline)
                                        .bold()
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("LabelTextColor"))
                                }.padding(.top)
                                
                                
                                if (item.description != nil)  {
                                    if let text = translate.getText() {
                                        Text(text.str).font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color("SubLabelTextColor"))
                                        .padding(.bottom)
                                        HStack {
                                            Spacer()
                                            if text.canBeTranslated {
                                                Button(action: {
                                                    text.toggleTexts()
                                                }) {
                                                    Text(text.isTranslated ? LocalizedStringKey("Original") : LocalizedStringKey("Translate"))
                                                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                                                            .foregroundColor(Color("SubLabelTextColor"))
                                                            .padding(.leading)
                                                    
                                                        Image(text.isTranslated ? "translated_white" : "translate_white")
                                                            .resizable()
                                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                            .padding()
                                                }.frame(height: 60)
                                                .modifier(NEUROMPHIC_BUTTON_PROFILE_MODIFICATOR())
                                                .padding(.top, 10)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Text(item.description!).font(.subheadline)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("SubLabelTextColor"))
                                        .padding(.bottom).onAppear(perform: {
                                            if let description = item.description {
                                                translate.setText(str: description)
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    StepDescriptionLoadingShimmer()
                                }
                            }.padding(.horizontal).padding(.bottom)
                            .background(Color("MainBackground"))

                    }
                }

            }
        }.background(Color("MainBackground").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical))
```

Comment: I believe you need to update the UI accoringd to "text.isTranslated". Please add more of your view where you declare this variable.

Comment: @dr-mucahid-erdogan have update my full view. Thanks for assistance